# JavaScript tree

Tags: javascript

I try to insert into array all the classes

for example

```
   <div class="class1">

   <div class="class2">

   <div class="class3">

   <div id="class4">

   </div> 
   </div> 
   </div> 

   </div>
```

And javascript

```
      var a=document.getElementById("class4");
  var b=new Array(a.parentNode.className,a.parentNode.parentNode.className,
  a.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.className);
  for(i=0;i<b.length;i++)
  {alert(b[i])}
```

This is work fine but my question is if I don't know how much parentNode there is to 
the class How can I loop all over the parentNode and insert it into the array?

Comment: I'm definitely not a web developer, but I'd perhaps a function that checks if a given element has a parent that is not document, then using a while loop with that function as the test?

Comment: But how can I get it without use parentNode.parentNode...

Comment: `This is work fine`? I doubt that. `class4` is a class not an id so `document.getElementById("class4");` wouldn't fetch the element.

Comment: Sorry I change it in my computer to check it and I forgot to change it here

Comment: Yes but I need the parents

Comment: Ah, I thought you were collecting the siblings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
​function allParents(node) {
    var arr = [];
    while (node) {
        arr.push(node);
        node = node.parentNode;
    }
    return arr;
}

console.log(allParents(document.getElementsByClassName("class4")[0]));
​
```

Comment: Note that document.getElementById from OP's question won't work because "class4" is a class name, not an ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the .parents() jquery method
http://api.jquery.com/parents/

Comment: the OP didn't mention about jquery